# Buscar un dato de un nodo en una lista

Tags: c, lista

Estoy intentando encontrar un dato de mi lista enlazada, en la cual la recorra hasta que sea null y decir si ese numero a buscar estar o no en la lista

Código:

```
aux=primero; 

while(aux != NULL && aux->dato != 50)
{
    aux=aux->siguiente;
}

if(aux->dato==50)
{
    printf("\n\n Numero %d esta en la lista",aux->dato);
}
else
{
    printf("\n\n El numero %d no esta en la lista",aux->dato);
}
```

Me salta un error diciendo que el programa dejo de funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que en caso de que no esté le estas preguntando a `NULL` si su dato es igual a 50. Una solución sería:

```
aux=primero;
int ok = 0, numeroABuscar = 50;

while(aux != NULL && !ok)
{
    if (aux->dato == numeroABuscar) {
        ok = 1;
    } else {
        aux=aux->siguiente;
    }
}
if(ok)
{
    printf("\n\n Numero %d esta en la lista", numeroABuscar);
}
else
{
    printf("\n\n El numero %d no esta en la lista", numeroABuscar);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sirvió

Comment: Me alegro mucho! Abrazoo!